# how to do number to string suffix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As you know in ruby you can do

```
"%03d" % 5
#=>  "005"

"%03d" % 55
#=> "055"

"%03d" % 555
#=> "555"
```

so basically number will have "0" prefix for 3 string places

just wondering is there possibility to do number string suffix in similar nice way ?
(please no if statements)

```
something 5
#=> 500

something 55
#=> 550

something 555
# => 555
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about ljust method?

```
"5".ljust(3, "0")
```

and some `to_s` and `to_i` method calls if you want to do that to integers

you could avoid string conversion with bit more math like `log_10` to find number of digits in an integer and then `i *= 10**x` where `x` is how many more 0's you need

like this:

```
def something(int, power=3)
  int * 10**([power - Math.log10(int).to_i - 1, 0].max)
end
```

Comment: really nice,  so your suggestion for speed is the log10 solution ? seems to me bit heavier than the ljust solution

Comment: I done speed test, the "ljust" solution is fastest solution https://gist.github.com/3122349  (and more cleaner :) )

Comment: well your test is not exactly fair to the int version as you do not test integer <-> string conversion. check this out: https://gist.github.com/3122511 - significant difference in favor of log10. + have to mention that [].max was the bottleneck as it was creating new array object on every iteration. max method can be inlined with much better performance obviously :)

Comment: anyway i'm impressed that ruby is so fast with strings, although probably i should be disappointed that it's so slow with pure math =/

Comment: :) good spot, we are getting total geaky on this don't we :) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
  def prettify(n)
    ("%03d" % (n.to_s.reverse.to_i)).to_s.reverse
  end
```

which

- converts your number to string
- reverses it
- converts it back to a number
- formats it
- converts it back to an int
- reverses it again

Maintaining this piece of code might become a challenge a few months from now, of course :-)

Comment: it's a solution but more like that "ljust" is provided by ruby straight away http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-ljust